# Why are pokerstars and party poker only available in software form?

Tags: software

I could have sworn I was allowed to play via a web browser in years past?

Are there any poker softwares available for linux users like me?

Comment: Linux had a project, but with no money, and I don't know if it is still active. You need a Windows installation. I have checked it with a Virtual Machine with a Windows installation and it works, I haven't checked using [wine](https://www.winehq.org/)

Comment: Another problem is all HUD's are only available for Windows.

Comment: Been a very long time since I played online, I used to affiliate for pokerroom.com, they had a windows client back in 2006, (they also stiffed me when everything went south in 2006), I have no real clue if they still have a web interface or even still are in business. but offered if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Because it is easier to catch cheaters. Also the random cart Pokerstars show come from a complicated physic device and they also use the click. Pokerstars want to know what you are doing in your computer, mainly to catch cheaters.